# PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME

Tags: vba, outlook

I have exported outlook email data to excel.

Now,another problem that I have come across is that the PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME do not display as the same date formats.
 The dates can be in *ddmmyyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM or mmddyyyy hh:mm* format ( Please refer to the img ).

 I have also made sure that all the cells format are general.
Is it possible to standardize the date format or there might be any other  reasons causing this?
[image: Display as different date formats (ddmmyyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM or mmddyyyy hh:mm)]

my code is as follows:

```
For Each itm In Items
'Check item type
If TypeName(itm) = "MailItem" Then
intColumnCounter = 1
Set msg = itm
intRowCounter = intRowCounter + 1
Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
rng.Value = GetLastVerb(msg)
End If
Next

Function GetLastVerb(olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String

Dim intVerb As Integer
intVerb = GetProperty(olkMsg, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003")
Select Case intVerb
    Case 102
        Debug.Print ("Reply to Sender")
        GetLastVerb = GetLastVerbTime(olkMsg)
    Case 103
        Debug.Print ("Reply to All")
        GetLastVerb = GetLastVerbTime(olkMsg)
    Case 104
     Debug.Print ("Forward")
        GetLastVerb = olkMsg.ReceivedTime
    Case 108
     Debug.Print ("Reply to Forward")
        GetLastVerb = GetLastVerbTime(olkMsg)
    Case Else
     Debug.Print ("Unknown")
        GetLastVerb = olkMsg.ReceivedTime
End Select
End Function


Public Function GetProperty(olkItm As Object, strPropName As String) As Date
Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA = olkItm.PropertyAccessor
GetProperty = olkPA.GetProperty(strPropName)
Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function


Function GetLastVerbTime(olkItm As Object) As Variant
GetLastVerbTime = GetDateProperty(olkItm, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040")
End Function


Public Function GetDateProperty(olkItm As Object, strPropName As String) As Date
Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA = olkItm.PropertyAccessor
GetDateProperty = olkPA.UTCToLocalTime(olkPA.GetProperty(strPropName))
Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind it very simple

The function `GetLastVerb` calls other functions which return a `Date` or a `variant` and then finally `GetLastVerb` returns a string. The best way is to simply format the output before writing it to the range

If you are not concerned with the `type` of final output i.e whether it is a string or a date then replace `rng.Value = GetLastVerb(msg)` by `rng.Value = Format(GetLastVerb(msg), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")`

If you want a proper date output then, format the column as relevant date/time format and then use `formula` to update the cell

For example

```
Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"

rng.FormulaR1C1 = Format(GetLastVerb(msg), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

Comment: Another thing is that i have also included Case else where emails are not being replied and the GetLastVerb = olkMsg.ReceivedTime.
It also gives different formats